# Displaying list of categories and tags in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sorting, tags, categories

I'd like to **display a list of categories and tags, that are picked manually**. So I'd pre-define what categories and tags are to be shown.

So there'd two blocks in the sidebar:

```
Major Categories
- category 1
- category 2
- category 3
... upto 7
```

and Tags:

```
Quick Links
- tag 1
- tag 2
- tag 3
... upto 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WordPress › WordPress Plugins << Search Plugins "dropdown categories"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=dropdown+categories)

Answer (score 1):

Look for a sidebar widget.
I don't think this is default functionality, because it is necessary to pick the tags and categires beforehand in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Categories Widget and this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-tags/

Answer (score 0):

For TAg clouds [use this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-columns/)  add your category whose you want to display in TAG Clouds...